# What are some good mining pools?

Tags: mining-pools

I'd like to try a bit of mining, but my GPU is way too weak to mine on my own. I've tried finding reviews on existing mining pools for ether but they're very sparse. Could you recommend a pool?

Comment: In general, lists are not well suited for Q&A sites. In addition, the quest for _good_ mining pools is way too subjective. Also this thread keeps generating noise from people trying to promote their own pools. I will put this on hold for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is about *good* mining pools, I want to highlight two pools which are unique in their appearance and tested by myself and considered to be *good*.

1. <del>[TalkEther](http://talkether.org/) is a **partially decentralized** mining pool. It is very interesting because it mines locally on your hardware and **eliminates any latency to the pool**. This works out because it locally sets the pool's account as coinbase. Once a block is mined locally it will immediately be broadcasted by your local client and eventually accepted by the network, without submitting it to the pool first.</del>
2. [EthPool](http://ethpool.org/) is a predictable solo mining pool. This means if you would mine solo with a defined hashrate, you would find a block every *x days*, *in theory*. EthPool sums up your *credits* and pays out a full block to you, **predictably, every x days**.

Happy mining. Don't choose the biggest pool by hashrate. That puts network consensus in danger.

Comment: [TalkEther](http://talkether.org/) has been down in maintenance mode now for quite a few weeks.

Comment: Why do big pools put network consensus in danger?

Answer (score 5):

[EthPool](http://ethpool.org/) has a visual display of pools and miners by hash power.

1. [DwarfPool](http://dwarfpool.com/eth) is a multi-coin pool that mines ETH and other coins.
2. [Coinotron](https://www.coinotron.com) is a multi-coin pool that mines ETH as well as other currencies.
3. [NanoPool](http://nanopool.org/) has been around for a while and is pretty stable.
4. [EthPool](http://ethpool.org/) is a "predictable solo mining pool", where the person who does the most work gets the whole reward.
5. [Coinmine](https://www2.coinmine.pl/eth/) is another multipool that mines ETH.
6. [Ethermine](https://ethermine.org) is another large multipool that mines ETH and other coins.

Remember, centralization of hash power is bad; try to pick a smaller pool, even if the payouts won't be as regular.

Comment: Downvote for promoting high hashrate pools, sorry, the question was about recommendations :)

Comment: Well, to be fair, high hashrate pools reduce payout variability, so they are better for OP, even if they're bad for the network.