# Alethone Hashing but no wei added

Tags: ether

Alethone finished synchronizations, the clircles were all full grey and green, then it started hashing showing numbers around 20. However, nothing is added and it shows zero wei.

I did that for a week, then upgraded ans it is still the same...

Any idea what is wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 20 kH/s it will you take an average of 9,454.09 days to find 1 Block. Rewards for solo mining are only added if you solve a block.

Please consider [pool mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1532/87) for the time being or upgrade your hardware.

Comment: Thanks. It is going at 20 MH/s. So I assume it will take 10 days.

Comment: I did try pool mining, but I am getting an error. It is trying to connect but can't. Is there anything I can do to fix that? Thx