# How fast should be an internet connection to mine ETH?

Tags: mining, ether, network

How fast should be an internet connection to mine ethereum and don't have connection issues? What about ping?

And, how many GB of data would get downloaded over a month period? I have a 250GB limit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How fast should be an internet connection to mine ETH?

I'm currently on a ~ 10 Mbits/s download and 1 Mbits/s upload line and it is fast enough to mine the Ethereum blockchain while performing my usual Internet usage, including videos.

In the daily chart below, the average data transfer rate seems to be between 200 and 358 Kbits/s.

### What about ping?

My ping time to the pool I'm currently mining with is between 359 - 432 seconds in a short test.

### And, how many GB of data would get downloaded over a month period?

**Note** - my estimates below are based on the raw bytes received and transmitted by my Ethernet networking cards on my mining computers and will include other traffic travelling within my internal network. It should be an over-estimate that will give you an upper limit.

[image: Ethereum Mining Network Traffic]

In the chart above, the daily traffic of 2.46 GiB received and 2.00 GiB transmitted would be a good representative of my Ethereum network traffic consisting of traffic from an instance of the `geth` blockchain node software and 2 instances of the `ethminer` mining software. My `ethminer` mining software has mainly been mining solo, but sometimes is pointed to mining with a pool.

In the monthly chart, the months of December 2015 to March 2016 would be representative of the Ethereum network traffic.

My monthly estimate from the charts above would be between 32 to 54 GiB downloads and between 25 and 91 GiB uploads, with the total transfers between 73 and 141 GiB.

### So

- You should be OK if you have a graphic proccessing unit (GPU) and want to mine the Ethereum blockchain and have a reasonably fast Internet connection with a 250 Gb download limit. If you don't have a GPU unit, see [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether/2393#2393) . But keep track of your data usage and stop the processing if you are nearing your limits.
- When **solo mining** the blockchain, your `geth` software will require you to download a current copy of the blockchain before mining can start. This can amount to between 4 Gb (using the `geth --fast` option) to 14 Gb for the full blockchain (`geth` without the `--fast` option).

  After the initial download of the Ethereum blockchain, your monthly data transfers may total between 73 to 141 GiB. You may be able to reduce this amount by limiting the number of peer connections your `geth` program connects to, using the `--maxpeers` command line parameter.
- You should well within your data transfer limits when **pool mining** the Ethereum blockchain. You will not need to download a copy of the blockchain as the blockchain is synchronised with the Ethereum network on the pool service's end. The pool will only send you small sets of data for your `ethminer` to perform it's computation, and `ethminer` will send back status reports and successful computation results.
- And if you do decide to pool mine, try not to use the largest (and larger) pools as there is too much concentration of hash power in these pools, and this is not good for the Ethereum network. You will find some of the pools listed at [etherchain.org - Miner Statistics](https://etherchain.org/statistics/miners) and further information in [What are some good mining pools?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/what-are-some-good-mining-pools/1554#1554).

---

#### Update Jan 31 2017

As requested by @gatb27, here is an update of my miner's network traffic. Note that my firewall reporting stopped sometime in October 2016, so the charts only display the data until then.

[image]

Comment: Hi @BokkyPooBah, thank for the explanation! Could you provide us with some updated data and maybe something about the light client implemented with Geth 1.5? :)

Comment: @gatb27, Some light client stats at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11295/1268 .

Comment: @gatb27, I've updated the network traffic chart, but my firewall stopped collecting data in Oct 2016 (usual upgrade breakage).

Comment: thank you very much for updating the post and also for the light client post :)

Comment: when the light client has to retrieve a value saved in a smart contract saved at address `smartContract_address`, what is the operation performed for asking the value to its peers?

Comment: Okay, dumb question. Is GiB "Gigabytes" or "Gigabytes in Bandwidth"? I'm just never seen GiB used as an abbreviation. Is it some mining term that I just don't know about? I did try googling.

Answer (score 7):

Mining itself doesn't use that much bandwidth, however syncing the block chain does. For syncing the blockchain using the --fast option it used about 12Gb(Initial sync) and about 100 mb the past 2 weeks. Mining itself used exactly 150mb for the past 14 days.

Comment: Interesting, are you mining on a `--fast` sync'ed client?