# How to estimate capex and opex

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, bootnodes

I'm doing some research about the use of open blockchain in different context. I'm trying to find the best way to evaluate capex and opex for:

- hardware requirements (full node vs light node with geth 1.5)
- storage requirements (full node vs light node)
- data to be downloaded daily (full vs light)
- bandwidth requirements (full vs light)

Do you have any insights? Do other researches about this already exist? :)

Thanks for your time like always!

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: [On bandwidth](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3839/87) and [link quality](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3138/87). On [disk space needs](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/143/87).