# How much internet bandwidth does keeping a Ethereum wallet use?

Tags: wallets

I have limited internet (250 GB per month) which I share with multiple people, so I have to make sure I don't use up too much. I downloaded the Ethereum wallet client, and it seems to take quite a while to sync. Will Ethereum use a considerable amount of my internet bandwidth?

Answer (score 5):

The Ethereum Wallet runs the `geth` client which is a full Ethereum node.

You can see my monthly bandwidth in [How fast should be an internet connection to mine ETH?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-fast-should-be-an-internet-connection-to-mine-eth) for a single `geth` node with 2 x `ethminer` mining instances, so my statistics should be similar to running the Ethereum Wallet continuously:

> My monthly estimate from the charts above would be between 32 to 54 GiB downloads and between 25 and 91 GiB uploads, with the total transfers between 73 and 141 GiB.

If you only run the Ethereum Wallet periodically, `geth` will catch up with the mined blocks in the blockchain and you will skip receiving and transmitting all the transaction data that `geth` processes when it is online.

Comment: If you are still running an Ethereum full node (as of March 2017,) can you comment on the current bandwidth requirements? Have they increased?

Comment: The bandwidth has remained about the same as documented in the link above. The reason is because I have one instance of the `geth` full archive node blockchain. The instance has the same maximum number of peer-to-peer connections. The blocks being generated at about the same rate (target ~14 seconds now, ~15 seconds before). It's only the incremental data being added to the full archive node blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

not much but 250GB / month will get eaten quite significantly by geth :

using nethogs I got this :

```
NetHogs version 0.8.1

    PID USER     PROGRAM    DEV        SENT      RECEIVED
  pid# myUser    geth       enp0s3   213.859      10.849 KB/sec
```

So it you double that 10KB/sec that's 52BG a month, that's one fifth of your allowed amount.

Comment: If you are still running an Ethereum full node (as of March 2017,) can you comment on the current bandwidth requirements? Have they increased?