# Specification of PC for being a miner

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, miner

Is there any specific software/hardware requirement for being a:
1- Miner
2- Node 
on a public network or any system configuration will work? Are there any recommendations? What specification most miners use ?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether

Comment: To summarize the answer in the linked question you need a GPU with at least 2 GB of memory to store the DAG. CPU mining is also possible but obviously not worthwhile.

Comment: See also http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/how-fast-should-be-an-internet-connection-to-mine-eth as you will need a fast enough Internet connection, with enough data transfer allowance. I would go for GPU with MORE than 2 GB of memory as some people have experienced some problems with 2 GB, requiring some additional configuration (see https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/5426/a-bunch-of-2gb-cards-stopped-working-tonight-because-of-dag-file-size), and the DAG file size only grows larger.